# grid html не ставятся кнопки

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, grid

[image: Как они распалагаются][image: Как должны распологатся кнопки]
1 как они распалагаются
2 как должны распалагатся

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calc">
        <div class="calc=screen">
            <p>0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons"> </div>
            <div class="btn ac bg grey">ac</div>
            <div class="btn plus-minus bg-grey">+/-</div>
            <div class="btn percent bg-grey">%</div>
            <div class="btn division bg-orange">/</div>
            <div class="btn seven">7</div>
            <div class="btn eigth">8</div>
            <div class="btn nine">9</div>
            <div class="btn multiply bg-orange">/</div>
            <div class="btn four">4</div>
            <div class="btn five">5</div>
            <div class="btn six">6</div>
            <div class="btn minus bg-orange">-</div>
            <div class="btn one">1</div>
            <div class="btn three">2</div>
            <div class="btn plus bg-orange">3</div>
            <div class="btn zero">0</div>
            <div class="btn zero">0</div>
            <div class="btn dot">.</div>
            <div class="btn equal bg-orange">=</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Проблемный участок с css

```
.buttons {
display: grid;
grid-template-areas:   
"ac plus-minus percent division"
"seven eigth nine multi"
"four five six minus"
"one two three plus"
"zero zero dot equal";
grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас лишний закрывающий `</div>` в строке `<div class="buttons"> </div>`.
Без него расположение элементов кнопок встает сеткой.

```css
.buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "ac plus-minus percent division" "seven eigth nine multi" "four five six minus" "one two three plus" "zero zero dot equal";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <div class="calc=screen">
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="btn ac bg grey">ac</div>
    <div class="btn plus-minus bg-grey">+/-</div>
    <div class="btn percent bg-grey">%</div>
    <div class="btn division bg-orange">/</div>
    <div class="btn seven">7</div>
    <div class="btn eigth">8</div>
    <div class="btn nine">9</div>
    <div class="btn multiply bg-orange">/</div>
    <div class="btn four">4</div>
    <div class="btn five">5</div>
    <div class="btn six">6</div>
    <div class="btn minus bg-orange">-</div>
    <div class="btn one">1</div>
    <div class="btn three">2</div>
    <div class="btn plus bg-orange">3</div>
    <div class="btn zero">0</div>
    <div class="btn zero">0</div>
    <div class="btn dot">.</div>
    <div class="btn equal bg-orange">=</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Гений! Отец русской демократии!